# Passing result-list from Multiprocessing Manager outside scope

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to scan domain for pentesting purposes, the program use Multiprocessing with the result-list got passed from Processes; back to main function.

I have tried to use Global Variables mentioned in `global` also in a `class`. Using this reminds me that the processes lives in different memory. So i'm using `manager.list()` instead; to share memory between processes

Here's what i've tried:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, cpu_count, Manager

class variably:
    variably=bla..
    .... 

def engine(domainlist, R):
    for domain in domainlist:
        try:
            r = requests.get("http://" + domain, headers=headers, timeout=0.7, allow_redirects=False)
            if r.status_code == expected_response:
                print("Success" + domain)
                print(domain, file=open("LazyWritesForDebugPurposes.txt", "a"))
                R.append(str(domain))
            elif r.status_code != expected_response:
                print("Failed" + domain + str(r.status_code))

        except:
            pass

def fromtext():
    ....
    R = []
    with Manager() as manager:
        num_cpus = cpu_count()
        processes = []
        R = manager.list()
        for process_num in range(num_cpus):
            section = domainlist[process_num::num_cpus]
            p = Process(target=engine, args=(section,R,))
            p.start()
            processes.append(p)
        for p in processes:
            p.join()
        print(R)
    print(R)

    print("")
    print(" Total of Domains Queried : "  + colors.RED_BG + " "+str(len(R)) +" "+ colors.ENDC)
    if len(inf.result_success) >= 0:
        print(" Successfull Result : " + colors.GREEN_BG + " "+str(len(R))+ " "+colors.ENDC)
fromtext()
```

Sorry for any invalid syntax or indentation, trying to simplify the codes into more shorter snippet.

Above codes returns `BrokenPipe` sometimes with `ConnectionRefused` error.
From the exception, i can see that the list already appended as: `['Domain.com','Domain_2.com']` but somehow raises an exception.

Here's some Screenshot about the problem:
[Problematic Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agMNY.jpg)

## EDIT:

It's looks like the list can only pass inside `manager()` scope, how can i extend the data passing outside the scope, for example calling the list in different function. This below codes works:

```
    with Manager() as manager:
        num_cpus = cpu_count()
        processes = []
        R = manager.list()
        for process_num in range(num_cpus):
            section = domainlist[process_num::num_cpus]
            p = Process(target=engine, args=(section,R,))
            p.start()
            processes.append(p)
        for p in processes:
            p.join()

        str(len(R))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem to this that i had to explicitly convert the `manager.list()` as another normal list by setting a new variable and use `global` to make it usable in another function. I know that it's dirty, havent tried using `Queue()` but for now, atleast it's working.

```
def executor():
    global R
    .... 
    with Manager() as manager:
        num_cpus = cpu_count()
        processes = []
        R = manager.list()
        for process_num in range(num_cpus):
            section = domainlist[process_num::num_cpus]
            p = Process(target=engine, args=(section,R,))
            p.start()
            processes.append(p)
        for p in processes:
            p.join()

        R = list(R)

    print(R)
```

If there's a simplification to this, i would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You really want to use a queue.  Create a `multiprocessing.SimpleQueue` in your main thread and pass it to all your subprocesses.  They can add items to this queue.

Creating your own manager is almost always a mistake.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, still trying to implement it but yeah, that's for the best.